# NSURLConnection Unable to http post large file

Tags: objective-c, ios, post, nsurlconnection, nsurl

We are trying to add in functionality into our app to allow it to POST a large file approx 50kb to our web service the file itself is a HTML template, however with the code below what we are finding is that the data seems to get cut off when the web service saves it.

The web service is currently designed to check the $_POST['html'] variable and write it to a file.

Is there a better way to do this and does anyone have any idea why the upload is not complete?

Thanks Aaron

```
   NSString *myText;
    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"template" ofType:@"htm"];  
    if (filePath) {  
        myText = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil]; 
    } 

    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mywebsiteurl.com/receiveData.php"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];
    request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";
    NSString *params = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"html=%@", myText];

    NSData *data = [params dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    [request addValue:@"8bit" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Transfer-Encoding"];
    [request addValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request addValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", [data length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];    
    [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:[request autorelease] delegate:self];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is because your Server set the post limit.Check the settings at your server side about the post data limit.

Comment: Hi, I dont think this is the issue I actually created a PHP script on another server which posted the same HTML file to this web service without any issues.

Comment: I also checked PHP.INI and the max post size is 8M

Comment: Maybe you can try posting the file directly use the multipart/form-data.

Comment: What was the solution here?

Comment: I leave my answer below because the characters is limit here.@PsychoDad

Answer (score 0):

When I rechecked this question, I think maybe I found what was the problem. When I do HTTP post, I usually don't set the `content-length` by myself. I just encode my post data as `key=value&..` form and use the `[NSMutableURLRequest setHTTPBody:data]` method to add the data to the `NSMutableURLRequest`. I think it will do the rest for you include set the content-length for you. Even though I am not very familiar with HTTP protocol, but I think maybe the `content-length` represent the whole post data length, but here you set the `content-length` value with the length of key value data length.