# AFNetworking Parameter Field Limit?

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

Is there a limit for the number of `POST` parameters in `AFNetworking`? I am using the following code but it seems to be not sending the parameters after `advert_preferred_occupation`

```
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];

NSDictionary *parameters =
  @{
     @"access_token": [self.defaults objectForKey:@"client_access_token"],
     @"advertType": advertType,
     @"advert_postcode": self.textFieldPostcode.text,
     @"advert_property_address_number": self.textFieldHouseNumber.text,
     @"advert_property_street_address": self.textFieldStreetAddress.text,
     @"advert_property_area": self.textFieldArea.text,
     @"advert_property_town": self.textFieldCity.text,
     @"advert_property_type": propertyType,
     @"advert_total_bed_in_property": totalNumberOfBedrooms,
     @"advert_total_number_of_bathrooms": totalNumberOfBathrooms,
     @"advert_total_number_of_rooms_to_rent": totalNumberOfRooms,
     @"advert_feature_garden": advert_feature_garden,
     @"advert_feature_wifi": advert_feature_wifi,
     @"advert_feature_parking": advert_feature_parking,
     @"advert_feature_balcony": advert_feature_balcony,
     @"advert_feature_concierge": advert_feature_concierge,
     @"advert_feature_gym": advert_feature_gym,
     @"advert_feature_elevator": advert_feature_elevator,
     @"advert_disabled_access": advert_disabled_access,
     @"advert_cost_per_month": self.textFieldMonthlyRental.text,
     @"advert_util_included": advert_util_included,
     @"advert_room_type": advert_room_type,
     @"advert_feature_furnished": advert_feature_furnished,
     @"advert_current_number_housemates": advert_current_number_housemates,
     @"advert_preferred_gender": advert_preferred_gender,
     @"advert_preferred_occupation": advert_preferred_occupation,
     @"advert_rules_pets": advert_rules_pets,
     @"advert_rules_smoking_inside": advert_rules_smoking_inside,
     @"advert_availability_date": self.textFieldAvailableDate.text
};
[manager POST:@"__MY__URL__" parameters:parameters constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {}
```

Comment: What the size of `parameters`? Could it be an issue on your server side? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32795507/soap-service-not-responding-if-message-length-greater-than-65535-in-ios8

Comment: There is no limit in AFNetworking. Perhaps the limit is in your server.

Comment: Thanks, I have taken a look at it and it seems to be working now.